# @RequestBody Map<String, Object> input getting int value

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/registrationuser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> getUserDetails(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> input) throws commonException  {
    Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    String email=(String) input.get("email");
    long id=(Long) input.get("userid");
    String password=(String) input.get("password");
    String rollid="1";
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setId(id);
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password));

    userRepository.save(user);

    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> retValue = new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(retMap, HttpStatus.OK);
    return retValue;
}
```

===

```
$scope.saveUserFunction = function(myVar) {
  console.log($scope.edituserdetails.email);
  console.log($scope.edituserdetails.email);
  console.log($scope.edituserdetails.username);
  console.log($scope.edituserdetails.password);
   console.log($scope.edituserdetails.id);

  console.log($scope.token);
  //$scope.user = {};
  // calling our submit function.


        $http({
            method  : "POST",
            url     : "/registrationuser",
            data    : {
            "email"     : $scope.edituserdetails.email,
            "username": $scope.edituserdetails.username,
            "password"  : $scope.edituserdetails.password,
            "userid": $scope.edituserdetails.id
            }

           })
            .success(function(data) {
              if (data.errors) {

              } else {
              //  $scope.message = data.message;
              }
            });
```

}

});

Getting below error for user ID. Why it is come as integer. I need to cast it as long as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your entity directly in spring-rest like:

```
@RequestBody User user
```

Afterwards the password then also could be reset.

Also the return value shouldn't be a `Map`.

```
return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
```